# Export GitHub acceptable SSH key in OpenSSH format from PuTTYgen

Tags: github, ssh, putty

I am adding an SSH key to my GitHub account.

To do that, I open PuTTYgen and press the button *"Generate"*.

When the key pair has been generated, I use the menu and open *"Conversions"* and *"Export OpenSSH Key"*.

Then I go into GitHub, settings SSH and GPG Keys, press *"new SSH key"* and paste the contents of the generated file into the textbox (adding the title *"github"*).

But I get a message about an invalid key.

> Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format.

Why?

I have also tried to

- Select *"force new file format"* and
- the normal *"save public key"* button

A solution would be to let GitHub create the key, but I have not seen how.

Answer (score 2):

Use the public key in the format shown in the PuTTYgen's *"Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file"* box.

[image]